# How can I deny public access to an AWS API gateway while allowing access by only a specific role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I would like to deny public access to an AWS API Gateway and only allow access when the API is invoked with a specific role. In my test there are two gateways, and one calls the other:

```
Public Gateway -> Private Gateway
```

I want to be able to visit Public Gateway endpoints in a browser and receive a 2XX response, and when visiting the Private Gateway directly I should receive a 4XX response. The only way to access the Private Gateway should be via the Public Gateway (which proxies to the Private Gateway with each endpoint).

I've tried several policies. All of these always result in the Public Gateway error logs showing the following:

> User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:********9012:abcd123456/dev/GET/products

That error message is received by the Public Gateway as a response from the Private Gateway.

Here are policies I've tried (separately):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcd123456/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-apigateway-role"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-apigateway-role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcd123456/*"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcd123456/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-apigateway-role"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcd123456/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcd123456/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-apigateway-role"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcd123456/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcd123456/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-apigateway-role"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcd123456/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-apigateway-role"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've redeployed with each Resource Policy change and waited one minute before testing.

The role is assigned in the Public Gateway's serverless.yml settings:

```
service: test-gateway

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true
  role: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-apigateway-role
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `/*/*/*` with `/*` in the **Allow** statement? `abcd123456/*/*/*`

Comment: Yep. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying this?

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow), if you **don't** specify an explicit `Deny`, and then provide a specific `Allow`, it should work. If it doesn't, keep sharing your outputs, I'm intrigued.

**Update**: I removed the Deny `*` part, this means we'll get an implicit deny for requests that are not specifically declared in an `Allow` statement. This is according to Sessions policies (see docs link)

**Update 2**: Check this answer's comments, the author also mentioned - *added  `authorizer: aws_iam` to serverless.yml*

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-apigateway-role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcd123456/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the same error when plugging in this policy and redeploying: `User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:********9012: abcd123456/dev/GET/products with an explicit deny`

Comment: What happens if you omit the Deny part? It'll act like an implicit Deny (Sessions policies)

Comment: Strangely the same error persists with just the Allow in place after a redeployment.

Comment: See CloudTrail logs to check who invoked what, and if you can afford it (security-wise) change everything in the Allow to an `*`, redeploy, invoke, check CloudTrail, and then set the policy according to what worked in CloudTrail

Comment: Thanks for all your help -- I appreciate it. Just can't seem to get things working. I think I'll probably have to use a VPC and actually make the Private Gateway truly private.

Comment: Super weird, I've tried this solution on my infra and it worked, I was able to invoke the function only by using an IAM Role, and I wasn't able to invoke it by sending an HTTP request to the API Gateway. I hope you'll figure out how to fix your issue

Comment: @ChadJohnson one last thing, in case it wasn't clear - in CloudTrail, you need to enable Data Events Log for Lambda functions, and then invoke the function with your Public API Gateway and with an HTTP request. After that, go to the S3 bucket, download the logs (might take ~5 minutes appear), download the log files and investigate the `role` attribute

Comment: Fixed it. Turns out I needed to add `authorizer: aws_iam` in my serverless.yml config for the Lambda function handler and sign my requests with an AWSv4 signature.

Comment: Also note that I am using `aws4-axios` to sign, and I'm using `AWS_PROFILE` when deploying from local. Assigning a role to the Public Gateway functions and then using the policy above for the Private Gateway was also necessary.

Comment: Glad to hear, I'll add a reference in my answer to your comments