# Acquiring an OAuth token from API Gateway pass through endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint which I usually call only from within my application. The endpoint returns data from an internal only restful api. To call it my application must use an oauth client ID and secret to acquire a token. This happens within my app without any user involvement because the user has not need to know about it.

I want to migrate my app to AWS as a serverless application which means the entire logic can be moved into the static site portion hosted on S3.

The only problem is that because I would not need a lambda or other serverside application I have no method to retrieve the oauth token securely and cannot make the internal API call.

I was thinking I could make an API Gateway configuration which could acquire the token by retrieving the ID and secret from Secret Manager, make the oauth token call and then apply the token to the header of the internal passthrough request.

Is this possible or do I definitely need a serverside app to acquire the token first?

Example journey:

S3 via CloudFront serves VueJS site > JS calls public API Gateway endpoint > Endpoint calls Secret Manager to get oauth credentials > Endpoint calls internal corporate (private) api to get oauth token > Endpoint calls internal corporate (private) endpoint to get data, passing token in header > Endpoint returns data to client

Comment: I think you could inject static information into the backend request, such as your token, but retrieving that token from secrets manager is probably not possible in the integration, that's where you'll probably have to involve Lambda.

Comment: I was thinking a little JS scripting in the response integration could be used to retrieve the token before injecting into the request header. But this would also require an api call in the JS to secret manager.

Comment: Unfortunately you're limited to things the Velocity Template Language (VTL) can do if I recall correctly. That's why you'll probably need to add a Lambda function as a translation layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [CloudFront Lambda @ Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html).

Since you're serving a static website with S3, putting it behind a CloudFront distribution will provide you the ability to serve your content securely with HTTPS (easier with AWS [Certificate Manager ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/)) and add an authentication flow by setting a Lambda@Edge function in the [CloudFront distribution's ViewerRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html).

Here are some examples of how to implement it:

- AWS blog-post - [Authorization@Edge using cookies: Protect your Amazon CloudFront content from being downloaded by unauthenticated users](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-using-cookies-protect-your-amazon-cloudfront-content-from-being-downloaded-by-unauthenticated-users/)
- AWS GitHub example - [aws-samples/cloudfront-authorization-at-edge](https://github.com/aws-samples/cloudfront-authorization-at-edge)
- Another GitHub example - [Widen/cloudfront-auth](https://github.com/Widen/cloudfront-auth)
- I also wanted to modify the [ViewerResponse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html#:%7E:text=Viewer%20Response), so I created my own implementation of the previous example - [devops-internal/cloudfront-auth](https://github.com/devops-internal/cloudfront-auth)

I usually use this solution to protect the staging environment (which is "public") from unknown users. Please mind the costs of this solution, see [Lambda@Edge Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/#:%7E:text=Lambda@Edge%20Pricing). If it's for a large organization, then this solution might be costly.

Comment: That’s very, very interesting but I’m not sure it answers my question. I will read into it, of course. My need is to make a call which is not made by the S3 static site, but by the internal infrastructure because I can’t let the client ID and secret be available in the S3 content.

Comment: Also it’s the internal service which needs to be secure as the application itself is public and has no user login.

Comment: @MattW Could you share the path of a simple request? For example Client --> S3 --> Infra (what's in here? ALB? EC2? ECS?)

Comment: I’ve added this at the bottom of the post. Was hoping to be able to provide a diagram but I’m doing this on mobile. The API Gateway endpoint would do all the work to get the data from the private, internal corporate API.

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958741/how-can-i-deny-public-access-to-an-aws-api-gateway-while-allowing-access-by-only) is relevant? It talks about adding another Private API Gateway, and maybe this API Gateway can do the "fetch SSM parameters" that you're talking about. What do you think?